# Regex Extract in Google Data Sttudio

Tags: regex, function, looker-studio

How am I able to extract a string from an array within a field? I am able to use Breakdown Dimension to get the array, but I can't seem to figure out how to use REGEXP_EXTRACT to get just the 'friendly_name'.

I tried this `REGEXP_EXTRACT(shared_attrs, '^friendly_name:\\s?"?([^";,]*)')` but that didn't work.

[image]

Comment: Remove the `^` at the start. `'friendly_name:\\s?"?([~^";,]*)'`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I get `null`

Comment: It looks like you want `'friendly_name"\\s*:\\s*"([^"]+)"'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(shared_attrs, 'friendly_name"?\\s*:\\s*"?([^"]*)')
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/nDVFbj/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```
- "friendly_name" - matches the characters friendly_name literally (case sensitive)
- '"?' - matches the character " with index 3410 (2216 or 428) literally (case sensitive) between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
 - "\s*" - matches any whitespace character (equivalent to [\r\n\t\f\v ]) between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
 - ":" - matches the character : with index 5810 (3A16 or 728) literally 
 - "\s*" - matches any whitespace character (equivalent to [\r\n\t\f\v ]) between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
 - '"?' -  matches the character " with index 3410 (2216 or 428) literally (case sensitive) between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
1st Capturing Group ([^"]*)
 - Match a single character not present in the list below [^"]
 - "*" - matches the previous token between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
 - '"' - matches the character " with index 3410 (2216 or 428) literally (case sensitive)
```